# Javascript - Show/hide - show active until click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a show hide script that is already in place but I'm having some difficulty in showing the 'active' div as soon as you enter the page. The div should then be hidden if another indicator is clicked and keep the same function as the rest of the indicators.

Here's my Html

```
<section id="slider">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv">   
             <!-- Indicators bullet -->
             <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
             </ol>
```

Here's my JS

```
function hideloop(){
    try{
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            $('#group'+i).hide();   
        }
    }catch(e){
        throw(e);   
    }

}
$(function(){
    hideloop();
    $('.carousel-indicators li').click(function(evt){
        var number = $(evt.target).attr("data-slide-to");
        hideloop();
        $('#group'+number).show();
    });
});
```

I've looked online and on stack but can't find this question.

Adam

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle link.

Comment: in hideloop() you're running `$('#group'+i).hide();` but i don't see any #group ids in your html. is it correct?

Comment: Its unclear. please be more specific.

Comment: The active indicactor you can get with `$('.carousel-indicators li.active').data('slide-to')` which you probably knew yourself. Outside of that I don't understand the question like Harry:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:-

```
function showHideGroup(){
    // hide all which has an id starting with 'group'
    $('[id^=group]').hide();
    // get the active group using data
    var number = $('.carousel-indicators li.active').data("slide-to");
    // show active group
    $('#group'+number).show();
}

$(function(){

    // call show/hide groups on page load
    showHideGroup();

    $('.carousel-indicators li').click(function(evt){
        // if this li is not active
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            // remove active from current active 
            $('.carousel-indicators li.active').removeClass('active');
            //add active to this li
            $(this).addClass('active');
            // show/hide relevant groups
            showHideGroup();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your html doesn't match your js, but regardless your hideLoop method needs to have an option to filter out the active element.

```
/**
 * @param {DOMElement} parent       The container element to close children of.
 * @param {DOMElement|null} active  The element you want to leave open. 
 *                                  Pass null to close all.
 */
function hideAllExcept( parent, active ) {
    var $parent = $(parent);

    var $children = $parent.children();

    if ( active !== null ) {
        $children = $children.not( active );
    }

    $children.hide();
}

// And the execution code
vsr $carousel = $('#slider .carousel-indicators');
var $active = $('.carousel-indicators .active');
$active = ( $active.length > 0 ) ? $active : null;

hideAllExcept( $carousel, $active );

$carousel.find('li').click(function(evt){
    var $current = $(this);
    hideAllExcept( $carousel, $current );
    $current.show()
});
```